# Meaning of "psychometrizing"?

Tags: meaning

This word is in "*The Demonologist the extraordinary career of Ed and Lorraine Warren*" couldn't find the meaning of it. When I Google it this word would come up "Psychometrics" which is not the same or I don't know maybe it's a misspell in the book.

Here is full passage:

> By the way, I should also mention that the name Steward or Stewart came through to Lorraine the minute she began psychometrizing the 401 parts.

Comment: Probably https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psychometry_(paranormal)

Comment: Considering the title, is it possibly a word the author of the book invented? It sure sounds like a short sequence in a "cold reading" show.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cold_reading